# Calculation of capacitor of deep trench DRAM

Tags: capacitor, memory, dram, calculation

If I know the depth of the trench **L**, the size of the DRAM node **D** and the thickness of oxide (say HfO2) **T**. How can I calculate the capacitor of a trench?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the "DRAM node"...do you know all of the dimensions of the trench or is this some parameter that may not be equal to critical dimensions? How accurate do you want your estimate to be? Can you provide a link to the source of the photograph?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem to me.  Even if it is, we usually like to see what work you've done so far.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have written something like this: I model the trench as a cylindrical capacitor paralleled with a semi-circle capacitor after seeing the telescope image of it. The second capacitor is too small to consider when the thickness is far smaller than the node size, so I just calculate the cylindrical capacitor to derive the refresh rate with the state-off resistance. Do you think my modeling is reasonable?

Comment: I think the information supplied is insufficient to answer the question. The photograph is too small to be of any use, so provide a better photograph or a better sketch then we can talk.

Answer (score 0):

In simplistic sense, it's a capacitance formula question. If we understand the area (3D cylinder in this case), we know the high-k material (dielectric constant) and "technology node (i.e. distance between anode & cathode is 20nm), we can estimate base capacitance. Series resistance will determine refresh rate and/or capacitor efficience... this should get you in the ballpark.

[image]